# Merging multiple C# dlls into one and exporting the merged dll for use in another project

Tags: c#, dll, windows-phone-8, ilmerge

I have a large solution in C# for Windows Phone 8 (VS 2012 Pro) composed of 12 projects which uses IsolatedStorage and several external libraries such as Newtonsoft.JSON, RestSharp, Unity for Dependency Injection, etc

One of the projects exposes several interfaces for functionality and acts as the main project. I want to merge all DLLs resulted from all projects in the solution into one DLL and use it in another project.

I'm looking for something similar to C++ static libraries. I want to include all code from all DLLs, including code from the 3rd party DLLs I'm using.

The final intent is to use my merged DLL as a distributable DLL for other projects.

How can I do this correctly?

I've tried with ILMerge command line but it throws errors because I'm using IsolatedStorage. I also tried with ILMergeGUI which seems to accept the fact that I use IsolatedStorage, but when I try to use the resulted DLL I get "Not Found" errors relating to my 3rd party DLLs.

Any ideas? Merging all the projects from the solution into one is possible, but not preferred (plus I would still need to statically include the 3rd party DLLs).

Answer (score 3):

**ilmerge** does **NOT** work for WPF applications. You might have a look at 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

Comment: The method suggested in the blog post is useful for EXE files, not for creating one DLL file. 
However there is some workaround suggested in the comments under the post: "The best option I can think of is to have the EXE (or host) explicitly call some initialization method in the not-embedded library so this method can register its interest in the AssemblyResolve event.

Another option, is to have various places in the assembly’s code register with the event using some kind of singleton pattern. That is, if the DLL hasn’t registered with the event do it else don’t do it. (...)"

Comment: Windows Phone 8 is not WPF it is based on Silverlight (with bits of WinRT and XNA) and each app is a DLL not an EXE... Not that this changes this from answer from "no".

Comment: @PaulAnnetts, so WinRT no longer belongs to managed dll, any suggestions to implement the required results? Thanks

Comment: That blog post was one of my first stops :D unfortunately, AssemblyResolve is not available in .Net for Windows Phone. All the DLLs I am trying to combine are WP Dlls. Now if there's any way to use normal .Net code in WP or if I can somehow create my SDK in normal .Net and use it in a WP application, that solution might be viable. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I've downloaded a trial version of .Net Reactor and it successfully merged my DLLs, but I am getting a System.TypeLoadException on mscorlib.ni.dll - any ideea what might normally cause this? All my dlls have the same runtime version (4.0), including my 3rd parties (I recompiled them). This error occurs when accessing a function that returns something. Object calls that return ready made instances work fine.